# Step by Step validation with jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms, plugins

I know its been asked many times already but no one could come up with solution so far.

The idea is to have one form separated into few steps and validate each step on next click of the button. I know jquery validation plugin is offering quite complicated way of doing it with accordion but can anyone come up with a simple solution something like

```
var stepOne = {
        rules: {
            fieldname1: "required",
            fieldname2: "required",

        }
    }

$("form").validate(stepOne); //onclick
```

hope someone could suggest the best way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: are you talking about wizard? than check [this](http://www.thecodemine.org/) out

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly what you're getting at, but why not just do separate forms altogether, get all the values together, and send them all in at once in the end?